# Add user authentication for tomcat

Tags: authentication, tomcat

I have been using Tomcat 7.0 and Eclipse Helios 3.6. I was asked to use a remote system as the tomcat server. i need to add user authentication for the remote server, so that only entrusted users can deploy apps on the server. To experiment with it, I configured tomcat-users.xml in conf folder 
Added

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

and restarted the server. I was not asked any username and password. 
Can any one help me to understand when the authentication is needed (is it when starting and stoppong the server and what are roles.

Thank you

Comment: you could accept some of the answers given to you as this may increase the help you are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you have a look through the Tomcat 7 docs [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access). The basic issue you are having is that the role manager-gui or similar must be added before authentication will work. there is also a line in server.xml that will need to be uncommented. it looks like the below :

```
  <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

the docs should help you out though.